# sort list divs doesn't work

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have to sort a multiple divs (which have "allDiv" class) according the text in the class "employe-name". The multiple divs are inside a dive which have "TeamTableContainer" id.

I got the text sore according "asc" and when I click on some icon a "desc" sort must be done and vice versaץ

The js code I use is:

```
  $('.formEmployee .sort-arrow').click(function(){
        if ($('.formEmployee .sort-arrow').hasClass('down')) {
        $('.allDiv').sort(function(a,b) {
                $('.formEmployee .sort-arrow').removeClass('down')
                $('.formEmployee .sort-arrow').addClass('up')
                console.log($(b).find('.employe-name').text().toUpperCase())
                return $(b).find('.employe-name').text().toUpperCase()  >$(a).find('.employe-name').text().toUpperCase();
            }).each(function( _, allDiv){
                $(allDiv).appendTo('#TeamTableContainer')
            })

            }
            else {
            $('.allDiv').sort(function (a, b) {
                $('.formEmployee .sort-arrow').addClass('down')
                $('.formEmployee .sort-arrow').removeClass('up')
                return $(b).find('.last-name').text().toUpperCase() < $(a).find('.last-name').text().toUpperCase();
            }).each(function (_, allDiv) {
                $(allDiv).appendTo('#TeamTableContainer')
            })
        }
    })
```

The sorting doesn't work as it should.
Why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: I think you'd want to have a look at sorting plugins like [tinysort](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/). They do the work for you.

Comment: Uh no, you have to include it in your project =)

Comment: Well yes, it's only a small JS to include. Then it does magic!

Comment: @Jeremy Thille- I added it but I got an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: tinysort is not defined"

Comment: How did you include it? And where?

Comment: In a gsp file. I use asse <asset:javascript src="redesign/plugins/jquery.tinysort.min.js"/>

Comment: Never heard of GSP. So I searched around and I found this : `GSP is an error message file sent by IMail Server, an email server program used by smaller businesses. It contains an error message or flag indicating a problem with the email delivery, typically generated by the mail server postmaster. GSP files are given in response to the sender of an email when there is an error.` Sounds totally unrelated to web development. What kind of architecture are you using? Just curious

Comment: Those `$('.formEmployee .sort-arrow').removeClass('down'); $('.formEmployee .sort-arrow').addClass('up')` things must be moved outside of the comparison function

Comment: @Bergi 1- I moved it. Still doesn't work good

Comment: @ Jeremy Thille- gsp is like html file. I used Grails

Comment: @ Jeremy Thille- the tinysort.min.js file did work. Wondering why the jquery file didn't work